# JavaFX Panes: Making a 1-pixel Border

Tags: javafx

I am struggling and will no doubt have to buy a manual to understand JavaFX CSS, or the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.3/docs/api/javafx.scene/doc-files/cssref.html)...

But what I want to do is make a 1 pixel border around some of my nodes, such as a `TableView` or `ScrollPane` on one side, and a `GridPane` or `ScrollPane` on the other side of a `Scene` I'm working on.  I say "or", because I'll take either one. Ha ha! 
(And regardless of whether it's filled up with controls or not)
Cheers.

Comment: Can you post some code and show what you have tried? The documentation you linked has pretty comprehensive descriptions of borders for `Region` (and consequently subclasses).

Comment: I haven't figured out where to put `-fx-border-width` for example (or `-fx-border-color`).  If I try these under `.scroll-pane`, or `.table-view`, then I do not get a border.

Comment: I will pull out a code example for this, since my colors may also be fooling me.

Comment: Tables and Scroll panes already actually have a 1-pixel border, in a medium shade of gray (slightly darker than the default background). The default stylesheet typically (including in this case) uses a technique of nested backgrounds to achieve this, but setting the border color with CSS adds another border too.

Comment: @James_D, In trying to put together a CCSSE, I found that my background colors were fooling my eyes, but the borders are there, as you say.  The only thing I don't find anywhere in the CSS is a GridPane.  I could make a code sample out of that, but fixed the other two.  You say "setting the border color with CSS adds another border"... ! What does it do with the original border?

Comment: 1. `GridPane` doesn't have a default css class, and doesn't have a border by default. So you need to add a css class and then define a border for that class. 2. If you have no insets, any border you set will sit directly on top of the default border for the table view and scroll pane. If you set `-fx-border-insets: 2;` the border you set will be inside the original border, with -2 it will be outside. It's late... but if I have time tomorrow I'll see if I can post an answer as there are quite a few ways you can do this.

Comment: @James_D, I could change this to a GridPane question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a test sample for demoing some ways to make borders in CSS:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewBorderTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        HBox root = new HBox(5);
        TableView<String> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(new TableColumn<String, String>("Data"));

        ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane();
        scroller.setMinWidth(200);

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setMinWidth(200);
        grid.getStyleClass().add("grid");

        root.getChildren().addAll(table, scroller, grid);
        // padding so we can easily see borders:
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("border-table.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // remove focus from tables
        root.requestFocus();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

You can run this with just an empty `border-table.css` file. The first thing to notice is that the table view and scroll pane already have a 1-pixel border in a medium gray (slightly darker than the default background):

[image]

This border is defined (see how later) in the default stylesheet, modena.css, and is set to a ["looked-up color"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor) called `-fx-box-border`. Just for demo purposes, to make it easier to see the border, you can reassign this color with the following in `border-table.css`:

```css
.root {
    -fx-box-border: red ;
}
```

This gives

[image]

Notice that the table header and column headers use the same color as a border. If you compare to the first image, you can probably see the borders more clearly in it too.

To replace the border in the table view and scroll pane, you can define borders in the css file. The simplest, but not necessarily the best, way is to define a `-fx-border-color`. Replace the `border-table.css` with the following:

```css
.table-view, .scroll-pane {
    -fx-border-color: green ;
}
```

The default value of `-fx-border-width` is 1, so this gives a one-pixel green border:

[image]

For the `GridPane`, note that it has no default border and also has no style class ([see CSS docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#gridpane)). In the Java code, I defined a style class for it:

```
grid.getStyleClass().add("grid");
```

so we can add the same border just by adding this style class to the selector:

```css
.table-view, .scroll-pane, .grid {
    -fx-border-color: green ;
}
```

[image]

It's interesting to note that the default stylesheet, [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) doesn't use `-fx-border-...` properties at all. Instead, it creates borders by creating two (or more) "nested backgrounds". For example, it has:

```css
.scroll-pane,
.split-pane,
.list-view,
.tree-view,
.table-view, 
.tree-table-view,
.html-editor {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
    -fx-padding: 1;
}
```

This defines, for `TableView`, `ScrollPane`, and other similar controls, two background colors. The first (so painted first, i.e. underneath) is a solid background fill in the looked-up color `-fx-box-border`, and the second (painted on top) is a solid background fill in the looked-up color `-fx-control-inner-background`. The first background fill has 0 insets, and the second has a 1-pixel inset, meaning that the bottom background fill will be visible for 1 pixel width around the edge of the control. (The padding ensures nothing is placed over this effective 1-pixel border.)

I haven't tested this at all, but it's claimed that the nested background approach is more efficient than drawing borders (I guess the native graphics is vey fast at rectangular background fills).

So you could use the same approach and replace `border-table.css` with

```css
.table-view, .scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color: blue, -fx-control-inner-background ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 ;
}

.grid {
    -fx-background-color: blue, -fx-background ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 ;
    -fx-padding : 1 ;
}
```

[image]

And you could even introduce a looked-up color to make it easier to modify the style of the app:

```css
.root {
    -my-border: blue ;
}

.table-view, .scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color: -my-border, -fx-control-inner-background ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 ;
}

.grid {
    -fx-background-color: -my-border, -fx-background ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 ;
    -fx-padding : 1 ;
}
```

(this has exactly the same effect as the previous, but there is just one place to change the color definition instead of two).

Note these last two versions override the default focus border, which is implemented in the default style sheet by defining a different set of background colors when the controls are focused. You can restore these with:

```css
.root {
    -my-border: blue ;
}

.table-view, .scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color: -my-border, -fx-control-inner-background ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 ;
}

.table-view:focused, .scroll-pane:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-faint-focus-color, -fx-focus-color, -fx-control-inner-background; 
    -fx-background-insets: -1.4, -0.3, 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 2, 0, 0;
}

.grid {
    -fx-background-color: -my-border, -fx-background ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 ;
    -fx-padding : 1 ;
}
```

which references two more looked-up colors, `-fx-faint-focus-color` and `-fx-focus-color` (the first is just a partially-transparent version of the second); of course you could redefine these for your own focus colors if you chose.

Comment: That is very insightful to the default (modena) behavior.  I get the 1-pixel grid border with the first simple example .grid class added (with an -fx-border-color).  What part of the GridPane is this border being rendered in?

Comment: By default (I believe) it is rendered on the pane itself, at the very edge. You can move it with `-fx-border-insets`.